How can we get FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of a device in Android?
I have a use-case were I want to use the the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) in Android-Device, which can be used to connect to a Device instead of using the IP-Address. FQDN will be consisting of the machine-name or host-name (Most common term) and the domain-name  i.e network-name (local domain assigned to that device).
Which API of Android I can Use here?
When connected to WiFi we can get the information regarding the connection using WiFiMgr, but couldn't find something related to FQDN in that, that can be used for communication purpose between two devices.
In windows I can get the local domain name using GetComputerNameExW () where i can pass Computer Format as ComputerNameDnsDomain which gets me the local domain of my machine. Is there an equivalent in android?

There is no requirement for an Android device to have a domain name. In part, that is because there is no requirement for a network to be associated with a domain name, let alone for a particular device on that network to have a name.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am looking for the api which can help me to retrieve local domain name associated with the device.
Have edited the question
